# Maximum value of a quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $n\ge 4$ be an integer. Define
$$A = \left\{ a = \begin{pmatrix} a_1 & \dots & a_n\end{pmatrix}^{\mathrm{T}} \in \mathbb{R}^n : a_1 + \dots + a_n = 0, \ \lVert a \rVert = 1 \right\}.$$

I need to find the maximum of the following quadratic form over $A$:
$$Q(a) = (a_1+a_2)^2 + \dots + (a_{n-1} +a_n)^2 + (a_n+a_1)^2.$$

I believe the answer is $2$, which is obtained by setting $a_1 = -a_3 = 1/\sqrt{2}$ and all other entries to $0$. However, I have no idea how to prove it.

Comment: Let $C$ be the Companion matrix for $z^n-1$ (this is a permutation matrix, also known as the cyclic shift operator) then you can write your quadratic form as $Q(\mathbf a)=\mathbf a^T\big(2I + C + C^T\big)\mathbf a$ where the matrix $\big(2I + C + C^T\big)$, which should have closed form spectra, and of course the ones vector is the Perron vector (dominant eigenvector).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$Q(a) = a^T B a$ where $a$ is represented as a column vector and $B$ is the $n \times n$ matrix with
$$ B_{ij} = \cases{2 & if $i=j$\cr 1 & if $|i-j|=1$ or $n-1$\cr 0 & otherwise}$$
$B$ is a symmetric matrix with eigenvalues $2 + 2 \cos(2 k \pi/n)$, $k=0 \ldots n-1$.
The eigenvector for the largest eigenvalue $4$ is $(1,\ldots,1)^T$, but you want your vector $a$ to be orthogonal to this (note that as $B$ is symmetric, eigenvectors for different eigenvalues are orthogonal).  So the best you can do is $2 + 2 \cos(2 \pi /n)$, taking $k=1$ or $n-1$, with a normalized eigenvector for that eigenvalue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How do we know that the maximum value must come from an eigenvector?

Comment: Express $a$ as a linear combination of eigenvectors, and you'll see.